# Get ipywidget button within a class to access class parameters through self?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am writing a class that I want to include multiple widgets that can be displayed in a Jupyter notebook.  These widgets should calls class methods that update class parameters. A function that I connect to an ipywidget's events need access to the class instance, I think through self, but I can't figure out how to get this communication to work.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = np.random.rand()
        display(self._random_button)

    _random_button = widgets.Button(
        description='randomize self.val'
    )

    def update_random(self):
        self.val = np.random.rand()
        print(self.val)

    def button_pressed(self):
        self.update_random()

    _random_button.on_click(button_pressed)
```

I see how the `button_pressed()` function sees the Button instance as `self`, giving "AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'update_random'".

Is there a way that I can access methods of the class Test through a button that belongs to the class, or is there a better way that I should be structuring this code to ease communication between these components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The button widget and the on_click should be created (or initialised) in the init method.
2. The on_click method generates an argument that is sent to the function, but it is not needed in this case so I have just put a *args in the button_pressed function.
3. The display call is not needed.
4. When calling a function in a class, you must use self.*functionName*. That includes the function calls in `on_click` or `observe`
5. In this case, you didn't need the random number generation in the init function.

There are a few examples of Jupyter widgets within classes here: https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot/tree/master/examples/Applications

```py
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.random_button = widgets.Button(
            description='randomize self.val')
        self.random_button.on_click(self.button_pressed)

    def update_random(self):
        self.val = np.random.rand()
        print(self.val)

    def button_pressed(self,*args):
        self.update_random()

buttonObject = Test()
# display(buttonObject.random_button)  # display works but is not required if on the last line in Jupyter cell.
buttonObject.random_button  # Widget to be dispalyed - must last last line in cell
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up for me.  This works as I wanted, and it has helped me to better understand classes.  Thanks especially for pointing out other improvements to the code that weren't strictly needed to produce the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When using JupyterLab, if you want the output to show in the notebook cell, rather than in the notebook log, a minor tweak is needed to @DougR's excellent answer:

```
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

# create an output widget
rand_num_output = widgets.Output()

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.random_button = widgets.Button(
            description='randomize self.val')
        self.random_button.on_click(self.button_pressed)

    def update_random(self):
        # clear the output on every click of randomize self.val
        rand_num_output.clear_output()
        
        # execute function so it gets captured in output widget view
        with rand_num_output:
            self.val = np.random.rand()
            print(self.val)

    def button_pressed(self,*args):
        self.update_random()

buttonObject = Test()
# display(buttonObject.random_button)  # display works but is not required if on the last line in Jupyter cell.
widgets.HBox([buttonObject.random_button, rand_num_output])  # Widget to be dispalyed - must last last line in cell, add output widget
```